# How do I convert rows to columns in MS Access using Ms-access query(select statment)

Tags: ms-access

please I want help with the following issue:
I have the following table named "CHECKINOUT" in ms ACCESS

```
     USERID      NAME        CHICKTIME
      1          K1        5:45:11 AM
      1          K1        3:45:12 AM
      1          K1        6:45:11 AM
      1          K1        3:35:13 AM
      1          K1        6:35:14 AM
      1          K1        3:35:15 AM
      1          K1        6:25:16 AM 
      2          K2        3:25:17 AM
      2          K2        5:25:17 AM
      2          K2        3:15:18 AM
      2          K2        3:25:19 AM
      2          K2        4:45:10 AM
      2          K2        2:45:11 AM
      3          K3        7:25:13 AM
      3          K3        6:15:14 AM
      3          K3        5:25:15 AM
      3          K3        3:35:12 AM
      3          K3        5:55:12 AM
      4          K4        5:05:22 AM
      4          K4        4:15:32 AM
      4          K4        3:55:42 AM
      4          K4        1:35:52 AM
      4          K4        2:43:42 AM
      .           .         .
      .           .         .
      .           .         .
      .           .         .
```

I want to convert the previous table to the get the  following result using MS-access query

```
    USERID      NAME    CHICKIN1    CHECKOUT1    CHICKIN2  CHECKOUT2     CHECKIN3  CHICKOUT 3  CHECKIN 4  CHECKOUT4 CHECKIN5
      1          K1     5:45:11 AM  3:45:12 AM  3:45:12 AM  3:35:15 AM  4:45:10 AM
      2          K2     10:45:12 AM 11:45:12 AM 1:45:12 PM  2:45:12 AM  3:45:12 PM
      3          K3     9:45:12 AM  10:45:12 AM  2:45:12 APM 1:45:12 AM 3:45:12 AM
      4          K4     8:45:12 AM  4:45:12 PM   4:45:12 AM  5:45:12 AM  5:45:12 AM
      .
```

The `CHECKIN`, `CHECKOUT`, `COLUMN_NIMBER` depend on the data in `CHECKTIME` for every user.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Ahmad. As air_blob already pointed out, please don’t use all caps when writing on the Internet (LIKE THIS), it’s considered impolite.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It could be impossible to do. I see that count of checkin and checkout diferent for every user & count may be very large. It will be better if you try to explain what the problem do you want to solve by doing this kind of convertation.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to select and copy the table in Access, and then create an empty file in Excel and then "paste special" and check the "transpose" checkbox. You will get a table of data that switching the original rows and columns.

Now, create the proper table headings in your Access and paste back the data.

Comment: Yes, Usualy I solve the problem by this method but it may be impossible because Excel has only 255 colums and around 65 000 rows.

Comment: Excel 2007/2010 support millions of rows and lots more columns (though I'm not certain what the new limitations are).